# Root dir reactjs

Tags: reactjs, package.json, manifest.json

When we create a reactjs project with the npm run build command, links to the "static" folder are created with a / before. Example: src = "/static/css...". When we are going to host on a domain... https://dominio.com/app. We have to update all links by removing the / or placing the static folder inside the root of the domain. How can we specify the root directory for /app/static when creating the project with the npm run build command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692588/react-js-running-npm-run-build-with-custom-paths

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `homepage` in your package.json

```
  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/app",
```

Here is  [Create React APP docs reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)